# display of ordered list items

Tags: html, css

I have: http://jsfiddle.net/Gkz4v/9/

```
.pagination li a {
    float: left;
      width: 6px;
      height: 6px;
      line-height: 6px;
      margin-right: 3px;
      text-indent: -9999px;
      background-color: #4b4b4b;
}
```

In the class above, if I remove line "float:left", result is displayed differently than if the line is there. Please try it in my fiddle above.

I want items on different lines with the effect of "float:left"

Can you please explain how does this work?

Comment: Not sure what you're tryingto do here.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve.  Using float: left is what makes your items be next to each other on the same line. If you want the items on different lines, don't use float: left.  What are you envisioning as the results of your idea to have 'items on different lines with the effect of "float:left"'?

Comment: thx for responding....I got my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `a` tag is an inline element by default, which do not obey widths and heights. `float`ing an element is one way to make it obey widths (which is why you noticed the effect), but in this case, you can just change the `display` to `block` to get your desired look.

```
.pagination
{
    padding: 3px 0 3px 3px;
}  

.pagination li a
{
    display: block; /* change here */
    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
    line-height: 6px;
    margin-bottom: 3px; /* changed the margin too, so it's nice and spaced out */
    text-indent: -9999px;
    background-color: #4b4b4b;
}

.pagination li.on a
{
    background-color: #1f84e3;
}

ol { list-style: none; } /* JSFiddle adds this automatically I think, but in the general case, this will remove the dots in the list */
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/PFhXs/).

Answer (score 3):

The effect that you describe, would be the size of the elements? You're trying to do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Gkz4v/10/

It is necessary to add a `display: block` in `<a>`. This is necessary because `<a>` is an element with `display: inline` and inline elements do not respect size rules.

Comment: No, he's right. If we're understanding what the OP wants, adding `display:block;` will make it display properly when `float:left;` is not there.